# localhost loads default apache page

Tags: macos, apache, mysql

I'm setting up a localhost and everything looks like it should work but whenever I go to site.local it loads the default Apache localhost page (It works!).

Here's a copy of my hosts file:

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1    localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%1o0 localhost

#####
 DEV
#####
# SITE
127.0.0.1    site.local
::1          www.site.local
```

and my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin test@test.com
    ServerName site.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/site"
    ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/site.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/site.local-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/me/site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Things I've done to make sure it isn't a user error:

- uncommented the line in the httpd.conf file to include my vhost file
- used `apachectl configtest` to test my file (came back saying syntax OK)

Things to note:

- I use port 8080 and 3307 for Apache and MYSQL
- If I go to site.local:8080 it loads but doesn't render the elements as it should (instead loads the elements of the html in a list format)
- this is off a FRESH install of MAMP
- OS: OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5
- MAMP Version: 3.5

I just don't see what's going wrong... any ideas?

**UPDATE**

localhost works as it should with port 80. 8080 = the default apache page, but 80 loads the site pages...

Comment: Can you post an screen shot of your browser with it on site.local:8080?

Comment: I can't no (not enough rep to upload one) - all it shows is a white page with 'it works!' in a h1 tag

Comment: I'm not seeing a `NameVirtualHost *:8080` directive prior to `VirtualHost` directive.

Comment: It's there (full vhost isn't posted)

Comment: It would help if you posted that as well (use pastebin).  Is your server configured to Listen on 8080 as well?

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to go to `site.local:8080` (with the 8080) in there or it won't work. Also, is it index.php or index.html that you are serving from your document root? If it is PHP, you need to set up PHP to parse the files and then configure Apache to let PHP parse files with .php. Course MAMP should be doing most of that for you.

Comment: @bassplayer7 I don't usually have to specify port to access my localhost? (I've had previous experience with other localhosts)

Comment: @Allan it is indeedy (it's running from my machine) and I can but it is the default httpd-vhost file just with the above added

Comment: HTTP's default port is 80 (TLS is 443), so I would estimate that you had configuration set up to work with port 80. Browsers will load port 80 without showing you that is the case. If you set up your Vhost for anything other than port 80 (again, unless you have a different scheme), then you will need to specific direct the browser to that.

Comment: @bassplayer7 well MAMP's default port is 8888 (which is stupid to begin with) so I changed it to 8080, changed name server, the *:8888 to *:8080, and MAMP does the rest for you in the httpd.conf, I have to have 8080 (to test localhost on Android devices Chrome requires port 1024 - 9999). Any other OS would work, with XAMPP on windows I have a different port that's changed easily and still works without specifying port, same with Linux, with Linux it's really eay.. just don't understand why MAMP + os x makes everything ten times harder haha

Comment: @klanomath sure will do so now

Comment: @TT12043205 Please add the paths of the files you are mentioning/editing. You have at least two relevant vhost files: one in MAMP and one in /etc/apache/.... Do you also run the OS X httpd daemon? What the purpose of localhost:80?

Comment: @klanomath the vhost is the mamp default one /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhost - not touched the /etc/ one

Comment: @TT12043205 Please sanitize your question. At least for me it's more and more unclear what you are asking, which results you are getting and which files you are editing and finally which results you want! Your **updates** don't help much either if you don't add what you have changed.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment that when you go to site.local:8080 you get a white page with the words "It Works!" similar to the screen capture below

[image: It Works!]

What you are seeing is the webpage based on the ***global server configuration*** where the *DocumentRoot* is whatever default MAMP is set for.

You mention in your OP that

> If I go to site.local:8080 it loads but doesn't render the elements as it should (instead loads the elements of the html in a list format)

Apache isn't going to render your webpage as a HTML list (unless you tell it to).  More than likely what you are seeing is a directory listing similar to this:

[image: Index Listing]

You get that listing because of the line `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` in your `httpd.conf` file.  If you want to disable this, remove the word *Indexes* from that line and the listing will no longer show up.

Your Virtual Host Configuration

First, we need to understand how Apache handles virtual host requests.  From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html):

> When a request arrives, the server will find the best (most specific)
>   matching  argument based on the IP address and port used
>   by the request. If there is more than one virtual host containing this
>   best-match address and port combination, Apache will further compare
>   the ServerName and ServerAlias directives to the server name present
>   in the request.
>
> If you omit the ServerName directive from any name-based virtual host,
>   the server will default to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)
>   derived from the system hostname. This implicitly set server name can
>   lead to counter-intuitive virtual host matching and is discouraged.

If you notice, ***your host that is defined the global server configuration*** is the same as the virtual host.

This is probably where you are getting your error.

Now, my fix for this is a bit more involved initially, but infinitely more efficient because I try to avoid turing my machine into both a client ***and*** a server.  I do all my development on a Mac with a Virtual Machine running my AMP server.  This way I can mirror my production environment much closer and I don't have unnecessary services (like Apache and MySQL) running on OS X; they are all relegated to the VM.  The VM has it's own IP, own server name, everything so when I point my browser to it, I know what results to expect.

I have a write up on how to install a FreeBSD VM on VirtualBox running on a Mac that has autostart enabled.  If you are interested, I can share it with you.

Comment: I absolutely agree that VMs are the best approach. That is something that I think the Mac really does well with. If you just need a simple box to run a CMS or something, Homestead is probably the easiest and quickest way to do that.

Comment: Exactly...I, prefer to use VirtualBox with a FreeBSD host configured as close to what the hosting providers give you so there is little or no fixing of things when you try to upload your site to a production server.

Comment: it doesn't show the file structure, it shows the html but without any styling. And it isn't the MAMP default page it's showing, it's showing apache's (MAMP's page is a weird hub kinda page). I could use a VM but I shouldn't have to.. I can do this on Linux and Windows easily, os x is the only one that makes life difficult? (sorry if this seems ranty haha)

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf and the results to a shared folder like OneDrive, Google Drive or Dropbox?  It's very hard to diagnose when you can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

1. Executing `apachectl configtest` doesn't check */Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf* for consistency but the default OS X Apache config file */private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*.

You have to use `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl configtest` instead to check */Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf*.

2. The use of a fully qualified domain name in the form *hostname.local* is discouraged. These fqdns are [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) for Multicast DNS (mDNS). You may use .home, .development or .test.

**Setup:**

MAMP/Apache/hosts configuration:

*/etc/hosts*:

```
...
127.0.0.1       site.development
127.0.0.1       www.site.development
::1             site.development
::1             www.site.development
```

Apache port in MAMP: 8080 (WebStart disabled!)

Content of the file *httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
...
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin test@test.com
    ServerName site.development
    ServerAlias www.site.development
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/site"
    ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/site.development-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/site.development-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/me/site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You may check your virtual hosts file with `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl -S`.

If you've set up your MAMP server properly and copied the default MAMP files *index.php* and *MAMP-PRO-Logo.png* to the folder /Users/me/site you will see the following "default" page:

[image: MAMP website default start page]

Entering *http://localhost:8080/* in the browser will show the same page.

If you run no other instance of Apache (especially the default OS X Apache) you won't be able to connect to [localhost:80](http://localhost:80) or [site.development:80](http://site.development:80).

---

If you run another instance of Apache (e.g. started by launchd or invoked by `sudo apachectl start` you can connect to it by either entering [localhost:80](http://localhost:80), [site.development:80](http://site.development:80) or http://site.development:80. You will see the default Apache page:

[image]

If OS X Server is installed additionally you'll get to a "Welcome to OS X Server" page after entering [localhost:80](http://localhost:80) even if *Websites* is disabled in Server.app:

[image]

Comment: the apachectl tests my MAMP one (I know this because I purposely created a bad vhost and it came back with the errors) - but aside from that I'll give this a go :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

`index.html`, `info.php`, `index.py` etc. reside under `/var/www` or `/var/www/test` or whatever you define in configuration. Look inside VM server whether UBUNTU or SUSE or whatever VMWare or VirtualBox and you cannot find `/var/www`. OS X doesn't play with open communities. There's no way you can make VM servers control browsers running on a Apple machine.